# Identify this fire truck set?

Tags: set-identification

Can anyone identify this fire truck set? I’d like to find the instructions before it gets taken apart.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [6752-1: Fire Rescue](https://brickset.com/sets/6752-1/Fire-Rescue)

[image]

Instructions:

- [Book 1](https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/4561939.pdf)
- [Book 2](https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/4565178.pdf)
- [Book 3](https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/4561942.pdf)